# OpenIDDict and OwinOAuthProviders

Tags: .net, openiddict

Since Identity Server 4 will achieve end of life in 2022, I am learning OpenIdDict. I understand the work flow of OpenIdDict and the samples have helped me in understanding it. Yet, there is only one thing which is unclear to me since no documentation/ samples an be found. How can you plugin external providers in to OpenIdDict (Google, GitHub, ...)? Are the packages from [Owin.Security.Providers](https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/tree/master/src) usuable? If yes, how could that be achieved then?

Answer (score 0):

> How can you plugin external providers in to OpenIdDict (Google, GitHub, ...)?

OpenIddict doesn't handle the user authentication part, which is something you'd configure independently. Of course, you can use any of the OWIN authentication handlers, including Google, Facebook or Twitter.

> Are the packages from Owin.Security.Providers usuable? If yes, how could that be achieved then?

Yes, they are. In a classical flow, you'd protect your authorization endpoint with `[Authorize]` and redirect your users to a login page where they could select the provider they want to use. To trigger a redirection to that provider, you'd have use the regular OWIN authentication `Challenge` API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn343601(v=vs.113)